# Magento - Postage price dependant on user group / discount

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Hoping someone here is able to help, I have a Magento Community store set up with a discount for wholesale orders, these are orders over a certain value made by customers logged in via a wholesale account, which is just an account with the customer group wholesale.

I’m trying to alter the postage cost just for customers making a wholesale order but have not yet managed to find a suitable way to get this to work.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You should use an extension, [like this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-and-payment-by-customer-groups.html). I do not use that one however I have purchased Amasty's extensions before.

In fact, thanks for asking this question, we'll need to review some of his latest work to see if we need to buy more...  :D